# In Reselect selector augment object with keyed objects if object key exist in another array

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

Trying to learn a concept. 
If I have Object of keyed objects and an array of keys.

```
const orders = {
    "key1" : { id: "key1", number: "ORD001" },
    "key3" : { id: "key3", number: "ORD003" },
    "key2" : { id: "key2", number: "ORD002" },
};
```

and an array:

```
const selectedOrders = ["key1","key2"];
```

and with the help of Redux `Reselect`. I want to have a new object like:

```
const orders = {
    "key1" : { id: "key1", number: "ORD001" selected: true},
    "key3" : { id: "key3", number: "ORD003" selected: false },
    "key2" : { id: "key2", number: "ORD002" selected: true },
};
```

So later I can iterate over that object via `Object.keys(this.orders)` and style selected items.
Is this correct to use Reselect for such use-case? If yes, then how should I check-in an efficient and idiomatic way, does an external array contains a given key?
If this idea is totally wrong for such use-case, then how should I do that in the right way?
Addendum: There also could be another array which contains keys in sequence how those orders should be displayed. (User is able to reorder items).
P.S. I don't want to use an array of objects for `orders` collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use reselect to combine two sets of data to produce a third set. Due to reselect's memoization, if the inputs don't change, then the calculation only needs to be performed once.

```
// You'll need some input selectors to pluck the raw orders from your redux store.
//    I'm making these up, since i don't know how your store is arranged.
const getOrders = (state) => state.orders;
const getSelectedOrders = (state) => state.selectedOrders;

const getAugmentedOrders = createSelector(
  [getOrders, getSelectedOrders],
  (orders, selectedOrders) => {
    const augmentedOrders = {};
    Object.keys(orders).forEach(key => {
      augmentedOrders[key] = {
        ...orders[key],
        selected: selectedOrders.includes(key),
      }
    });
    return augmentedOrders;
  }
);
```

If you have a lot of selected orders, then doing `selectedOrders.includes` every time through the loop may be a performance problem. In that case i'd create a Set of the selectedOrders, since lookups into the Set will be constant time.

```
  (orders, selectedOrders) => {
    const selectedSet = new Set(selectedOrders);
    const augmentedOrders = {};
    Object.keys(orders).forEach(key => {
      augmentedOrders[key] = {
        ...orders[key],
        selected: selectedSet.has(key),
      }
    });
    return augmentedOrders;
  }
```

Comment: Thank You! For confirmation and for working examples!